# Retrieve rows with highest value with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| Id | Label | Width |
|----|-------| ------|
| 0  |   A   |   5   |
| 0  |   A   |   3   |
| 0  |   B   |   4   |
| 1  |   A   |   7   |
| 1  |   A   |   9   |
```

I want to write a function that takes the rows with same id and label A and filter it based on the highest width

so the after applying the function the dataframe would be:

```
| Id | Label | Width |
|----|-------| ------|
| 0  |   A   |   5   |
| 0  |   B   |   4   |
| 1  |   A   |   9   |
```

Comment: Try `df.loc[df.groupby(['Id', 'Label'])['Width'].idxmax()]` or `df.groupby(['Id', 'Label'], as_index=False).max()`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thank you so mcuh! but how can I specify the label to be A only

Comment: So you dont want to consider label `B` when filtering the rows with the highest value per `Id` and `Label`? What happens when there are more than two rows having label `B`, do you need to keep them all?

Comment: Exactly. I'm not considering label B, only label A

Comment: What happens when there are more than two rows having label `B`, **do you want to keep them all?**

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try:

```
m = df['Label'].eq('A')
df_a = df.loc[df[m].groupby(['Id', 'Label'])['Width'].idxmax()]

df_out = pd.concat([df[~m], df_a]).sort_index()
```

**Details:**

Create a boolean mask with [`.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) specifying the condition where `Label` equals `A`:

```
>>> m

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: Label, dtype: bool
```

filter the rows using the above mask and group this dataframe on `Id` and `Label` and aggregate `Width` using `idxmax` to get the indices on max values:

```
>>> df[m].groupby(['Id', 'Label'])['Width'].idxmax().tolist()
[0, 4]

>>> df_a

   Id Label  Width
0   0     A      5
4   1     A      9
```

finally `concat` the above dataframe with the dataframe containing labels other that `A` and `sort` the index to maintain the order:

```
>>> df_out

   Id Label  Width
0   0     A      5
2   0     B      4
4   1     A      9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` to get your desired outcome:

```
df.groupby(['Id','Label'],as_index=False)['Width'].max()

   Id Label  Width
0   0     A      5
1   0     B      4
2   1     A      9
```

And combine it with `set_index()` and `loc`, to get more specific results:

```
label = 'A'
df.groupby(['Id','Label'],as_index=False)['Width'].max().set_index('Label').loc[label]

       Id  Width
Label           
A       0      5
A       1      9
```